# mysql count join double results

Tags: mysql, join

Table structure:

**activities** id, name, tagId

**activitiesTags** id, title

**activitiesReactions** id, activityId, message

The query now:

```
SELECT A.id as activityId, A.name, A.tagId, T.id, T.title, COUNT(R.id)
FROM activities A
LEFT JOIN activitiesTags T
ON A.tagId = T.id
LEFT JOIN activitiesReactions R
ON R.activityId = A.id
GROUP BY A.id
ORDER BY A.id DESC
LIMIT ?
```

The problem is that I'm getting a reactionCount, but it is far from true, It seems that when an activity has an reaction, it times (*) the amount of actual reactions by two.

Does anyone know where the problem might be? Maybe the ORDER BY after GROUP BY?

Thanks

Comment: it's because you are joining with tags as well

Comment: I see, so should I devide it into 2 queries? Just join the tags in another query? or a union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@knittl

Some modification to your query:

```
SELECT a.* , group_concat(T.title)
FROM ( 
    SELECT A.id as activityId, A.name, A.tagId, T.id, T.title, COUNT(R.id) 
    FROM activities A 
    LEFT JOIN activitiesReactions R 
    ON R.activityId = A.id 
    GROUP BY A.id 
    ORDER BY A.id DESC 
    LIMIT ? 
) a 
LEFT JOIN activitiesTags T 
ON a.tagId = T.id
```

`group_concat` will display all tags with delimiter (","). your query will display only the first one.

Comment: There are not multiple tags, only multiple reactions (but I only need the count of the reactions not the actual reaction data)

Comment: If I understood the recent comments, there will only be a single tag per activity. Also, my query will get all tags, but only one per row

Comment: Ah oke this works, but now the next step: usersFriends, and yes now I'm throwing in another table, I need activities of all the friends of a certant user so I have another table: usersFriends (id, userId, friendUserId). Before I did: SELECT A.id etc... FROM usersFriends UF LEFT JOIN activitiesTags WHERE UF.userId = ? so how do I do that?

Comment: @knittl, `GROUP BY` will dismiss the other tags, as MySQL display only the first row item.

Comment: @user1066101, I think to make a seperate query  and then ` wjere a.user in (1l,2,3,4,5,6). It simpler and faster than other join.

Comment: @MosheL: The `GROUP BY` happens inside the subquery and does not affect anything outside of the parentheses …

Answer (score 2):

You are grouping on `activities.id` (or `activitiesReaction.activityId`, whichever way you put it). By joining with your tags table you will get a new row for each tag that matches the given activity. Your count does not double, but is multiplied by the number of tags for each activity.

You want to use a subquery to add the tags to your previous resultset:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT A.id as activityId, A.name, A.tagId, T.id, T.title, COUNT(*)
    FROM activities A
    LEFT JOIN activitiesReactions R
    ON R.activityId = A.id
    GROUP BY A.id
    ORDER BY A.id DESC
    LIMIT ?
) a
LEFT JOIN activitiesTags T
ON a.tagId = T.id
```

This will give you the correct `COUNT`, but it will still return multiple rows per activity.

Comment: Can I fix it by using a union, else I have to put a foreach loop after the query and go through all the activities (might be like 200) so for each activity I would have to query the database again, would be a pretty big loss of performance right?

Comment: @user1066101: What is the goal you are trying to achieve exactly? A possibility would be to use a subquery, give me a second

Comment: I want a list of activities, each activity can have a tag (not required so left join, only ONE) and each activity can have reactions (not required and can be MULTIPLE reactions per activity), but I want to get the count only because later on users will see the activity COUNT, and if they click on the activity itself it will load the ACTUAL reactions (so it will not load everything at once + can update it realtime with json).

Comment: If there is only a single tag EVER per activity, your posted query should work as expected. Are you sure there is only a single tag per activity? Try removing the `GROUP BY` statement and inspect the returned recordsets, if they are actually what you expect